# Is there a geometric interpretation of the unoriented string theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, string-theory

I am having troubles in understanding conceptually what are *unoriented* strings in string theory.

Parameterizing the string with the spatial coordinate $\sigma$, Polchinski states (in his Volume I *String Theory* book) that there is a symmetry realized by the change of orientation $\sigma \to \ell - \sigma$. He argues that quantum mechanically, this transformation is realized by an operator $\Omega$ whose action on open and closed string states reads, respectively,
$$ \Omega | N ; k \rangle = (-1)^N |N; k \rangle \tag{1.14.20a} $$
$$ \Omega |N; \tilde{N}; k \rangle = |\tilde{N}; N;  k \rangle \tag{1.14.20b} $$
The **unoriented** string theory is then defined by resctricting to the states with $\Omega = 1$.
This implies for example that the open string states with odd $N$, such as the massless photon, are thrown away.

However, it is not clear for me if there is a geometric, worldsheet representation of the unoriented string states, or if this is an abstract definition, relying on the interesting property that $\Omega$ is multiplicatively conserved in interactions.

For example, Polchinski later makes a drawing of two worldsheet contributions to the (open string $\to$ open string) amplitude
[image: Polchinski's two-open-string amplitude]
arguing that amplitude (b) acts as $\Omega$ on the right intermediate string, so that the sum of the two diagrams $1 + \Omega$ acts as a projection operator, projecting onto unoriented string states for the intermediate strings on the right. I guess this implies that unoriented string states remain unoriented in interactions. However, I don't understand Polchinski's label arguing that the figure on the right is an "unoriented" contribution.

Is there a relation between the non-orientability of the worldsheet as a geometric surface, and the unorientedness of the string ?

Comment: For an oriented open string, the two ends can be distinguished from each other -one end is blue, the other is red. The ends of un-oriented open string are indistinguishable -- both ends are blue. Oriented closed strings have a "direction". Imagine painting a red, blue and green dot along the string so you can always distinguish the direction red --> blue --> green. There are no such distinguishing marks on an un-oriented closed string. Note that The painting of dots is, of course, just presented here as a toy model.